# Open and close single Websit multiple time in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have scenario where I have 12 plant id for which I need to access single Websit 12 times to download the report one by one.

Not worked on webscraping hence seeking help from expert

Comment: *Not worked on webscraping ...* without a [mcve] it's hard to help you at all. In general you can create a loop and call the url each time in the loop

Comment: Please include your code so we can see what is going on. There isn't even a question above. Implicit [please help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) is not a question.